# Submitting item within a form

Tags: c#, forms, anglesharp

[Edited 10/01/18 to give more background on the code. This version present the complete code used]

I am struggling a bit with a form submitting using AngleSharp.

I use AngleSharp to Scrap this website for [Proxies](http://www.gatherproxy.com/proxylist/anonymity/?t=Elite) addresses. Basically I open the website with AngleSharp and a IBrowsingContext (Page in my code)

I then SubmitAsync the Forms[0] to have the full list of proxies (see the website link to understand what I mean) and read the different proxies there [this part is not presented here].

It then got more complicated when I want to navigate within the different pages (usually around 60 pages with a navigating bar at the bottom, i.e. Forms[1](http://www.gatherproxy.com/proxylist/anonymity/?t=Elite) in the Page).

As advised by Florian Rappl I turned on the ressource loading based on an example he gave ([see here](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp.Samples/blob/master/AngleSharp.Samples.App/ViewModels/MainViewModel.cs)). In the code posted below I commented with the memory usage as it seems the ressource loading loop download something with the memory usage skyrocketting. For comparison I provided the memory usage without the ressource loading. This is a fully workable code for a console app.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ASTester().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

.

```
static async Task ASTester()
    {
        var Handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            PreAuthenticate = true,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        };

        var Client = new HttpClient(Handler);
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");

        var Requester = new HttpClientRequester(Client);

        var Configuration = AngleSharp.Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader(setup =>
        {
            setup.IsResourceLoadingEnabled = true;
        }, requesters: new[] { Requester }).WithJavaScript().WithCss();
        var Page = BrowsingContext.New(Configuration);


        /*At this point : 
         *              Mem usage : ~15 MB
         */

        /*Open the page with the proxy list 
         *      with setup.IsResourceLoadingEnabled = true; 
         *              Mem usage : ~80 MB
         *      without
         *              Mem usage : ~35 MB
         */
        await Page.OpenAsync("http://www.gatherproxy.com/proxylist/anonymity/?t=Elite");

        /*Submit the first form (id = 0) which will activate the bar to navigate within the different pages
         *      with setup.IsResourceLoadingEnabled = true; 
         *              Mem usage : 300 MB
         *      without
         *              Mem usage : ~50 MB
         */
        await Page.Active.Forms[0].SubmitAsync();

        /*Activate the script to go to page 2
         *      with setup.IsResourceLoadingEnabled = true; 
         *              Mem usage : 1.5 GB
         *      without
         *              Mem usage : >> Exception
         */
        Page.Active.ExecuteScript("gp.pageClick(2);");

        //Giving time for the script to execute
        Thread.Sleep(40000);

    }
```

Half of the time the script execution throw an exception. For the rest the Page.Active evaluation is `'((AngleSharp.Dom.Document)((AngleSharp.BrowsingContext)Page).Active).ActiveElement' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the anchor elements you've shown here rely on JavaScript. See this part `onclick="gp.pageClick(2);"` - it is certainly not executed when you navigate (actually navigating here will just go to the defined anchor `#2`, which normally should not re-load the page, but apparently it does - the page is empty because the original page was retrieved via a form POST, while this new one is retrieved via a GET w/o the form data).

The AngleSharp scripting lib only works (atm) for really simple scripts. Once, e.g., Angular, React etc. or even specific versions of jQuery are required the scripts won't work. You could try `document.ExecuteScript("gp.pageClick(2)")` to see if this has some effect, where `document` would refer to `Page.Active` in your example.

TL;DR: Many pages require (excessive) JS use these days. Before comparing AngleSharp with the browser make sure that either AngleSharp has no problem with the JS on the page, or that you turn off JS in the browser to have an exact comparison of the behavior w/o JS.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried but it gives me a Javascript exception : `gp is not defined`

Comment: Then I think AngleSharp cannot handle the JS on the page. When `gp` is not defined the JS that defines `gp` did not work. On a side note: Are you sure the JS is loaded?! I don't see your requester config, but you need to turn on resource loading, which is disabled by default.

Comment: The only reference to JS is there `_configuration = AngleSharp.Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader(requesters: new[] { requester }).WithJavaScript().WithCss();` Nothing else.

Comment: What you posted is the AngleSharp configuration - a reference to JS is something like `<script src="foo.js"></script>` which should request the file foo.js and run its content. (that is meant with "are you sure JS is loaded" - it's not about AngleSharp's capability to run JS, but rather about the site's JS)

Comment: I posted the configuration in reference to your question regarding loading the JS. // What I understand from your answer is that I should have some declaration of `gp` somewhere in the webpage source code. There is this in the <head></head> `<script src="/content/js/gp.zipped.js?v=118" type="text/javascript"></script>`.

Comment: Yes, but again - how it specifically looks is not interesting to me (and kind of useless info here). What is interesting (and you need to answer that) is if that script is successfully loaded (i.e., downloaded at all in the first place, and successfully executed afterwards). Since `gp` is not defined I don't think it is (now its a matter if its not downloaded, see my original remark regarding resource loading, or just a failure during execution).

Comment: I don't have a clue how to check if the script is loaded - but given the fact that I got a `gp is not defined` exception I'll go with the obvious and say no. Regarding the ressource loading I understood from https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp.Scripting - The library comes with a service that exposes WithJavaScript to IConfiguration. This enables automatic evaluation of script elements that have a valid JavaScript type - that the WithJavaScript() was enough.

Comment: No this is wrong. `WithJavaScript` only integrates a JS engine and does not fiddle with resource loading (that would be a very negative side-effect). Such AngleSharp functionality is always following the SRP and thus constraining to its purpose, i.e., interpreting JS code. If your JavaScript is in external files AngleSharp won't load it if you did not enable resource loading.

Comment: So how exactly do I enable resource loading? Should I create an instance of `AngleSharp.Network.Default.ResourceLoader`? I see I have to pass a context to it so `var rLoader = new ResourceLoader(Page);`. Still not sure how it should work. Do I have to `rLoader.DownloadAsync(**scriptsourceaddress**);` and then execute the script? Do you have any source in the github repo with an exemple of the use of resource loading?

Comment: You could look at the sample app repo (https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp.Samples/blob/master/AngleSharp.Samples.App/ViewModels/MainViewModel.cs, this one uses the requesters from AngleSharp.Io, but `WithDefaultLoader` from the core works similar). In general, see my initial comment that you did not post the requester configuration. Resource loading is enabled by setting the respective options in the `WithDefaultLoader` helper.

Comment: Ok so I changed the configuration like this `_configuration = AngleSharp.Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader(setup => { setup.IsResourceLoadingEnabled = true; }, requesters: new[] { Requester }).WithJavaScript().WithCss();` My requester is an HttpClientRequester. If you need i'll post the full code. For sure now it's loading stuff : loading the page use now around 100Mo of RAM and submitting the form skyrocket at 726Mo (vs ~80mo before)....

Comment: Code Posted. Maybe we can clean a bit the comments